# JavaScript text area: add line break

Tags: javascript

I want to display an output in my HTML text area using Javascript, but I cannot figure out how to insert the line breaks. Based on other answers I found here, I tried this:

```
txtResults.value = "Route: " + route + "\\\n" + "Start Station: " + stnStart + "\\\n" + "End Station: " + stnEnd;
```

but the output comes out as

```
Route: A>B>C
\
Start Station: A\
End Station: C
```

but if instead of `\\\n` I put `\\n` the output comes out as

```
Route: A>B>C
\nStart Station: A\nEnd Station: C
```

how do I make it like as follows?

```
Route: A>B>C
Start Station: A
End Station: C
```

Comment: Instead of randomly trying different combinations of back slashes, why don't you read up on how escape sequences in JavaScript strings work? Start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"\n" works right?

```js
var route = "A>B>C", stnStart="A" , stnEnd = "C";

document.getElementById("textarea").value = "Route: " + route + "\n" + "Start Station: " + stnStart + "\n" + "End Station: " + stnEnd;
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" style="width:100%;display:block" rows="5"></textarea>
```